# New to Java trying to make a switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to make a switch that will step through the code like in Javascript by adding  "jedi++" at the end but it won't let me do that any suggestions on how I can accomplish that?  Here is a snippet of the code.

```
switch(jedi){
    case 1:         
        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("guardian") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("sentinel") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("consular")){           
            System.out.println("Please enter the path followed by this Jedi.");
            System.out.println("(Guardian, Sentinel or Consular)");
        }
        registrant.setPath(input);
        break;

    case 2: 
        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("master") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("knight") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("padawan")
                    && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("youngling")){
            System.out.println("Please enter the Jedi's Rank.");
            System.out.println("(Master, Knight, Padawan, Youngling)");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
        }       
        registrant.setRank(input);
        break;
    jedi++;
}
```

Comment: Please be informative. _"it won't let me do that"_ is not.

Comment: It also looks like you have 1 too many `}` in the second case.

Comment: Sorry it stats that I couldn't convert a int to string didn't realize I had it as a string and not a integer

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to jedi++ in all the cases or just in case 2?

If it's just for case 2, you could do

```
case 2:
    ....
    jedi++;
    break;
case 3:
    ....
```

if it's for all the cases, you could do jedi++ after the switch block.

Answer (score 1):

Statements can exist only within the case. since jedi++ is not part of case, its throwing error. Putting the increment statement under required case statement will solve the issue.